# Sampling prior covariance matrices - nested sampling

Tags: covariance-matrix, prior, wishart-distribution

I am trying to fit a multivariate Gaussian with a non-diagonal covariance matrix $\Sigma$ using [nested sampling](https://dynesty.readthedocs.io/en/latest).

Usually, in other Bayesian analyses, we would use a Inverse Wishart or LKJ prior on the covariance matrix and compute the posterior using the analytical form of the prior.

However, in [nested sampling](https://dynesty.readthedocs.io/en/latest), we cannot do this. We must specify the prior in terms of a transform from uniform uncorrelated samples. For instance, for a 1d normal prior, the prior transform would be the percent point function of the normal (the inverse of the CDF). `norm.ppf(uniform_samples)` gives you samples from the prior.

Unless I am mistaken, there is no function to transform uniform samples into a Wishart or LKJ prior.

Is there a better prior for covariance matrices that has a usable transform? Or is there a technqiue to estimate these transforms? Using a uniform prior on covariance matrix elements seems foolish.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at codes generating random inverse wishart matrices (e.g, Jones 2007).

For example, the scipy implementation (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.6.0/scipy/stats/_multivariate.py#L2754 functions rvs, _rvs and _standard_rvs) use chi² and normal random draws and combines them with linalg.

You can take each normal/chi² variable based on a transform of the unit cube, and then follow the same procedure to obtain the matrix.